# Is there an idiomatic way to unwrap each returned Result from an iterator?

Tags: rust, idioms

Say I have something like the following, where `Tag::from` returns a `Result<Tag,&'static str>`:

```
let upcased = "ABC".to_string();
let chan_vec:Vec<Tag> = upcased.chars().map(|c| Tag::from(&c).unwrap() ).collect();
```

Is the second line the best I can do style-wise?

Comment: Answers to the duplicated question do indeed give the idiomatic approach to handling errors in iterators. However, if you do need to unwrap the results, causing a panic in case of errors, your approach is perfectly valid and there is no shorter way (though there can be minor tweaks, e.g. unwrapping in a second `.map()`).

Comment: Does the lifted `Result` have the contents from the first error returned if the result is `Err`?

Comment: Yes, I believe [that's how it works](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/result.rs.html#954).

Comment: Thanks, just tested in http://is.gd/LwoPat